British acting stock company

Country: UK
Year: probably 1980s
Plot: Set in a regional stock company. There's an affair between a stage-struck young woman and a director or a leading man.
Actors: I thought I remembered Alan Rickman, but can't find it in his filmography.


A movie, right?

Sounds a lot like Mike Newell's UK drama An Awfully Big Adventure with Alan Rickman & Hugh Grant, but it's from 1995.

Set right after World War II, a naive teenage girl joins a shabby theatre troupe in Liverpool. During a winter production of Peter Pan, the play quickly turns into a dark metaphor for youth as she becomes drawn into a web of sexual politics and intrigue. 

She's struggling on the stage and has an affair with a lead actor in the troupe played by Rickman. Here's the trailer:




Many thanks, Walt! Don't know why I'd mentally misfiled it so :-(
